# max_element in lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda, max

I implemented this function but it still give the following error and I can't figure out why..

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:6325: error: no match for call to '(Farm::killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm()::__lambda0) (Animal*&, Animal*&)' if (__comp(*__result, *__first)) ^
```

I searched some examples on the internet and I cannot see what's the difference between mine..

My .cpp file had the following killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm

```
Animal *Farm::killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm()
{
    auto minmax_widths = std::max_element(animals.begin(), animals.end(),
            [] (Animal const& lhs, Animal const& rhs) {
                return lhs.getWeight() < rhs.getWeight();
            });
}
```

Comment: What is "the following error"?

Comment: Your function has no return statement and does not return `void`, so your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: I bet it's because `animals` is a `std::vector<Animal*>`. (I'm totally guessing here)

Comment: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:6325: error: no match for call to '(Farm::killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm()::__lambda0) (Animal*&, Animal*&)'
  if (__comp(*__result, *__first))
                                ^  , this is the error. And it is ineed a vector Mohammad, should I just just create a new pointer value?

Comment: *"And it is ineed a vector"*  It's a vector of **pointers**.  That's what the error telling you - it's failing to pass *pointers* to your lambda function.

Comment: And how to solve this?

Comment: How is this unclear -- your vector contains apples, and your lambda expects oranges. Change the lambda to like apples.

Comment: Which is to say, the 'compare' lamdba needs to be written to accept pointers to Animal (not references as it is currently written)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Or better yet, change the vector to contain oranges.

Answer (score 9):

If `animals` is `vector<Animal*>`  then change your lambda function to :

```
       auto minmax_widths = std::max_element(animals.begin(), animals.end(),
            [] (Animal const * lhs, Animal const * rhs) {
            return lhs->getWeight() < rhs->getWeight();
    });
```

The alternative is to make `animals` a `vector<Animal>` in which case your lambda works as is.