# C++ Finding max value in a vector of vectors

Tags: c++

I'm still pretty rusty with C++, so would like to know if there is a more concise way of finding the maximum value in a vector of vectors. Here's what I have come up with:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> score;
```

This `score` variable is populated by some other code. I want the max value stored:

```
int max_value()
{
    std::vector<int> row_maximums;

    for (auto row = score.begin(); row != score.end(); ++row)
    {
        row_maximums.push_back(*std::max_element(row->begin(), row->end()));
    }
    return *std::max_element(row_maximums.begin(), row_maximums.end());
}
```

I'm largely a C# dev so would normally be used to doing it on one line with LINQ:

```
List<List<int>> score;

public int max_value => score.Aggregate(0, (current, row) => row.Prepend(current).Max());
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Your second example uses a [LINQ lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/convert-foreach-linq?view=vs-2022), vs. a  C# "for" or "foreach" loop. C++ has lambdas too, since C++11.  Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32030490/421195.  cptFracassa gives another excellent example [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74754314/421195).  REMEMBER: "less code" isn't necessarily "better", or "more readable".  There are always potential tradeoffs.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you can use C++20, I would simply write:

```
auto max_value = std::ranges::max(score | std::views::join);
```

`join` flattens the vector from 2d to 1d, and `max` gives you the max value of the range

Working example: [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/jaKvYxGrP)

Answer (score 0):

```
int max_value()
{
    int ret = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    for (auto& row : score)
    {
        for (auto& j : row) {
            if (j > ret)
                ret = j;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Just want to show that things maybe much simpler than you thought :D

the `for (auto& row : score) {...}` is equivalent to `for (auto it = score.begin(); it != score.end(); ++it) { auto& row = *it; ... }`, but shorter in this scenario. (only available since C++11 of course)

Comment: And much performant without allocate that all in one big grand list, if that matters.

Answer (score -1):

```
int max_value()
{
    int value = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    for (auto &row : score)
    {
        if (!row.empty())
            value = std::max(value, *std::max_element(row.begin(), row.end());
    }
    return value;
}
```